# Why Does Parallel.ForEachAsync Use All Threads On My Box Waiting Using AsyncManualResetEvent?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, parallel.foreachasync

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get a particular record before I process the rest.

Unfortunately, I don't have the freedom to enumerate twice to get the 1 record I need before processing the rest. I do know that the record I'm looking for will be one of the first records from the Enumeration but my understanding is `Parallel.ForEachAsync` does not guarantee order.

This is a scaled down version of how I'm using it in my project. Conceptually the same, but more basic.  I am using [Microsoft VS for the AsyncManualResetEvent](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/AsyncManualResetEvent.cs).

If you run it, it freezes because it uses all available threads on the box.

My thinking was that the `WaitAsync` would allow threads to do other work. So either a flaw in my understanding of `Parallel.ForEachAsync` or `AsyncManualResetEvent`.

Anyone know how to solve this using a `Parallel.ForEachAsync` or another Parallel mechanism?

```
var mre = new AsyncManualResetEvent();
        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(1, 1000), async (i, _) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("iteration {0}", i);
            if (i == 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("begin set {0}", i);
                mre.Set();
            }

            await mre.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine("released {0}", i);

            // Do work now that we have 20
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong tool. What kind of thing are you enumerating? Can you put each element into some other kind of priority queue?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Streaming rows from file. Thousands of rows. Only problem is I need the header row before I can proceed. Wondering if memory is really a concern or if I should just materialize all the rows.

Comment: IMHO parse the rows as an enumerable of some strong type, process them in `Parallel.ForEachAsync`.

Comment: Do you mean just materialize (ToList, ToArray, etc) into memory and process in Parallel.ForEachAsync?

Comment: Does your example also lock up your machine or just when you try and read rows from a file in parallel?

Comment: No, I mean that you should write a file parser like `IEnumerable<Record> Parse(IEnumerable<string> lines)` which should do the absolute minimum to read the header, then parse each line of the file (or whatever a record looks like), and yield them one at a time.

Comment: *"it freezes because it uses all available threads on the box."* -- How do you know that it freezes for this reason? Do you see the CPU usage skyrocketing, or the numbers of threads used be the process goes over the roof?

Comment: I'm not sure `IEnumerable` is the best abstraction when reading from a file. `Stream` might be more appropriate, at least until you have read the header. Then you could have one thread reading the rest of the file and one or more doing the processing. Also, "Thousands of rows" is not a lot, possibly not even worth doing on a background thread. I would really recommend doing some profiling/measurements before trying to optimize.